# How to change the appearance of expander icon wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a user control, using the `expander` control and I want to change only the appearance of `expander` icon.

could someone please tell me how to do.

Comment: Does this help: http://blog.ninlabs.com/2011/04/keeping-it-simple-customizing-the-wpf-expander-icon/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change icon expander in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090524/how-to-change-icon-expander-in-wpf)

Comment: You're going to have to make a copy of the Template and modify it manually.

Answer (score 2):

There is not direct way to do that.  You need to write the whole `Template` for the control.

As mentioned by @Noam, the [Codeproject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248112/Templating-WPF-Expander-Control) is really good to go.  But, the problem is, it wont work for different `ExpandDirection` of `Expander`.  I have modified a bit to make it work on all directions.  You can make use of the following if needed.

**[Expander with animation that support all direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031258/expander-with-animation-that-support-all-direction)**

Also, you can modify the `Arrow` icon of `Expander` as you like.